# LCM Inequality proof

Tags: integers, gcd-and-lcm

i have a question that i cannot solve

let a,b,c be positive integers such that b divides c
prove that

```
LCM(a,b) <= LCM(a,c)
```

so far i tried to go with the definition of gcd and division but it does not help
because i cannot prove that gcd(a,b) > gcd(a,c)
so if anyone can give me a lead or a tip that would be great!

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3):

$\mathrm{lcm}(a,c)$ is by definition a multiple of $a$ and $c$. Because $b|c$, it is also a multiple of $a$ and $b$. By definition of $\mathrm{lcm}(a,b)$ as the *least* common multiple of $a$ and $b$, you have directly $$\mathrm{lcm}(a,b) \leq \mathrm{lcm}(a,c)$$

Comment: But cant c be a multiple of b but not of a?

Comment: I did not use the fact that $a$ divides $c$, where do you see that ?